# TypeError: Cannot call method "setSchema" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

I am trying to connect a Google Spreadsheet with Google BigQuery for that I created a Google Apps Script but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Cannot call method "setSchema" of undefined.
```

The code calling `setSchema` is the following

```
var loadJob =  BigQuery.newJob()
    .setConfiguration(
      BigQuery.newJobConfiguration()
      .setLoad(
        BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad()
        .setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON")
        .setSchema(sshema)
        .setDestinationTable(json_table.getTableReference())
      )
  );
```

When I view the log for `sshema` I get a correct `JSON` like

```
 {fields=[{name=first, type=STRING}, {name=last, type=STRING}]}
```

I am not sure how to solve the error, when I comment out the `SetSchema` line the error goes away...but obviously the script does not do what its suppose to.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I tried debugging the script and the line that is suppose to create the `newJob()` simply inserts the `{}` value into the `loadJob` variable. I am not sure why this is not working but at least it seems to be the problem.

Comment: seems related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401220/bigquery-functions-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary bug, should be fixed in a week. You can track it at:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2906

In the meantime, you can bypass it by not chaining the sets(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420247/132438