# BigQuery Functions Not Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

The bigquery functions in our apps script had been working fine all along but 18/06/2013 onwards `setProjectId()`, `setQuery()` and other `BigQuery` functions have stopped working.

On using these functions, the variables remain undefined when they should ideally be populated.

A small sample script which reproduces this issue:

```
var newJobReference = BigQuery.newJobReference().setProjectId(yourProjectID);
var jobConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration().setQuery(yourJobQueryConfiguration);
```

Anyone facing the same issue? What might be causing this?

Comment: This is a temporary bug, should be fixed in a week. You can track it at:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2906

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved when I use:

```
var newJobReference = BigQuery.newJobReference();
newJobReference.setProjectId(yourProjectID);
```

Instead of:

```
var newJobReference = BigQuery.newJobReference().setProjectId(yourProjectID);
```

Comment: This is an open bug, to be fixed soon: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2906